# In which book are the hand movements written while recting vedic mantras?

Tags: vedic-rituals, vedic-chanting

While reciting vedic mantras I witnessed some people making some actions with hand.
I want to learn them. Where can I learn them from. Is there a refrence book for it ?

Link to videos where I found it:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjxifFNyNFA
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23ZgFI8RkMc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XlBNfqlXXk

As mentioned in comments that there is not much documentation of it, why is it so ? Are these HastraMudras not important? Can they be skipped?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. This is the method of Veda-recitation by two shakas within the Shukla Yajurveda - Madhyandina & Kanva. Both employ hand gestures. The former has more movements, and "variations" than the latter.

Comment: I don't think such book exists, but even so it will very difficult. Take a look at [this](https://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/ved_vedang_gp_24/#book/2) and [this](https://youtube.com/user/pranavmuley89) channel for Madhyandina shakha.

Comment: @Proxy Since no book exists, are these hastra mudras not much relevant ? Can they be skipped while reciting mantras ?

Comment: No, they cannot be skipped. The lack of books is because it is to be learned from a guru. There are vedic schools which specialize in teaching the vedic chanting of a perticular shakha. If you want to do it without them, go for taittiriya shakha which has no hasta mudras.

Comment: Please watch this video =>> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihEoC9767AA